# Reading in 64 byte chunks from a file in C

Tags: c, algorithm, blowfish

I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept of reading in 64byte chunks, then using the blowfish,

```
BF_cfb64_encrypt(source, dest, sizeof(source), &bf_key, iv, &enc, BF_DECRYPT)
```

function to encrypt? it. I know how to use the BF function, but reading in 64 bytes, from say a 4096 byte file is my confusion. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. My understanding is that 1 char is a byte, so does that mean I simply keep a count and when char count is 8 then that means I have read 64 bytes, hence encrypt, then write to file, and repeat until the entire file is parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, familiarity with your stream cipher is probably warranted. Blowfish encrypts/decrypts using a block size of 64 *bits*; not bytes. So long as you understand the 64 "bytes" you're referring to is *your* requirement and not Blowfishes, and that Blowfish only requires 8-byte blocks.

That said, a loop passing over a file with a size that is a multiple of the algorithm block size, extracting decrypted data one 64 byte frame at a time is certainly doable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <openssl/blowfish.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // your key bytes would be here (obviously).
    unsigned char key[16] = "1234567890123456";
    int key_len = sizeof(key)-1;

    // setup the key schedule.
    BF_KEY bf_key;
    BF_set_key(&bf_key, key_len, key);

    // and setup the initialization vector. normally the IV is
    //  randomly generated when encrypting, then stored as the
    //  lead 8 bytes of ciphertext output. this assumes you're
    //  iv is static (all zeros) similar to SSH
    unsigned char iv[8] = {0};
    int n = 0;

    // finally, begin reading the data in chunks of 64 bytes
    //  sending it through the blowfish algorithm
    unsigned char source[64];
    unsigned char dest[64];
    while (fread(source, sizeof(source), 1, fp) == 1)
    {
        BF_cfb64_encrypt(source, dest, sizeof(dest), &bf_key, iv, &n, BF_DECRYPT);

        // do something with your dest[] plaintext block
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

That sample is fairly trivial, but it brings up some things about symmetric block algorithms and padding that you may not be considering (or perhaps you have, and it simply has nothing to do with this question).

Symmetric block algorithms like Blowfish operate on a block size. In the case of Blowfish that block size is 64 **bits** (8 bytes). This means that the encryption/decryption operation always happens in 64-bit-sized chunks. If if you were using the lower level openssl apis you would have to encrypt (and decrypt) the data in blocks no larger than that. The higher-level APIs (such as `BF_cfb64_encrypt`) are designed to allow "stream mode" meaning you can submit your data in larger chunks, so long as they're sized to be a multiple of the block size. *and* you retain the `iv` and `n` values between chained successive calls to the API.

Finally, I started writing this rather long diatribe about symmetric block algorithms and padding modes, but realized this isn't really appropriate to this question, so I can only suggest you research into them. I've a suspicion you'll need to at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Why donot you use read system call?

**Required Include Files**

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

**Function Definition**

```
size_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

**Parameters**

**int fildes** : The file descriptor of where to read the input. You can either use a file descriptor obtained from the open system call, or you can use 0, 1, or 2, to refer to standard input, standard output, or standard error, respectively.

**const void *buf** : A character array where the read content will be stored.

**size_t nbytes** : The number of bytes to read before truncating the data. If the data to be read is smaller than nbytes, all data is saved in the buffer.

**return value** : Returns the number of bytes that were read. If value is negative, then the system call returned an error.

**Sample**

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   char data[128];

   if(read(0, data, 128) < 0)
       write(2, "An error occurred in the read.\n", 31);

   exit(0);
}
```

** Pseudo Code **

```
int no_byte_read = 0; // Will store number of byte read
void *buffer; //temporary storage for read data   
FILE *fp; //File pointer of the file to be read 

buffer = (void*) malloc(64); //Allocate space to temporary buffer.

fp = open file to be read;

do{
      no_byte_read = read(fp, buffer, 64); // read 64 byte from file and store in buffer
      if(no_byte_read < 0){
           printf("Error occoured in read");
           break;
      }
   }while(no_byte_read == 64) //If this condition is true that means still some bytes
                                remain in file which must be read.
```

Comment: Suppose a file has 500 bytes, will it read it all eventually?

Comment: Use a loop to read 64 byte chunks. And check return value of read each time if return value is 64 then everything is fine. If returned value is less than 64 that means end of file reached. If returned value is negative then read error.

Comment: so is if(read(0, data, 64)<64) correct or do I have to check less than 0

Comment: Suppose file size is 500 byte then in ideal case read will return 64, ceil(500/64) times ie 7 times. and in 8th iteration read will return (500 - 7*64) ie 52.

Comment: You have to check for negative number too as part of safe practice, because in case of read failure read returns negative number (so you must abort). But till you are getting positive number, read is successful. Also the first parameter will be the file descripter of the file you are reading from.

Comment: I understand it all thus far, but only confusion is why did you ask me to see if it returns 64? should I be doing two checks? can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes you have to use 2 checks. read returns the number of byte read. so if it is returning 64 that means more bytes are still left in the file to read. if it is 0<= return value < 64 that means end of file is reached. Let me post a pseudo example.